# What do I need to do if I am to setup a Mail server on a RaspberryPi?

Tags: email, webserver, raspberry-pi, imap

I have a pi and want to have a mail server for myself and my small team of 5 devs.
Initially I setup sendmail to send mails from this server, but now I wish to receive and access mails as well (via IMAP).
I do not expect a full fledged how-to for this, since from what I've understood, setting up such a thing involves,

1. Knowledge of setting up web-servers (for listening for incoming mails)
2. Access rights management (to limit only registered users to access their mails)
3. Setting up DNS MX records

I already have good experience in all of the above, but what I'm not coming to grasp is, how do I take all this knowledge and setup my own IMAP enabled email server.

Comment: I would first check to make sure your ISP doesn't block incoming connections on port 25 or any other mail-related ports. If they do, there's no point in trying to continue unless you can convince them to give you access.

Comment: IMAP runs on 445 or 993 for secure IMAP.  Get an IMAP server like dovecot and configure it.  Dovecot will optionally listen on either or both ports.

Comment: 2. Register users.  Your local server only to responds to accounts or aliases you have setup on your server.  You can set your server up to use local accounts or accounts on a mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

[https://lelutin.ca/posts/installing_postfix_-*clamav*-*spamassassin*-*dovecot*-_postfixadmin_on_debian_squeeze/](https://lelutin.ca/posts/installing_postfix_-_clamav_-_spamassassin_-_dovecot_-_postfixadmin_on_debian_squeeze/)

This article provides in detail the setup and testing of a mail server.  I did not write, but see the end of the article for a complete bibliography.

If you do choose postfix in your main.cf you need at least these exclusion for weak security protocols.  If your clients are all using TLS add SSLv3 to the list.

smtpd_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, eNULL, EXPORT, DES, RC4, MD5, PSK, aECDH, EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA, EDH-RSA-DES-CDC3-SHA, KRB5-DE5, CBC3-SHA, SSLv2